# Definition of conditional expectation for singleton

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. Furthermore, let $X, Y$ be two random variables from our probability space to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.

I have learned the definition of both $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}]$ as well as $\mathbb{E}[X | Y] := E[X | \sigma(Y)]$, however, I don't know what the following means $$E[X | Y=y]$$ where $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Does this just mean that the random variable maps any $\omega \in \Omega$ to $y$? This does not really make sense to me because then the $\sigma(Y)$ would just be $\Omega$ right?

Comment: This usually denotes a measurable function $f$ such that $E[X|Y] = f(Y)$. (Under the usual conditions — in particular if $Y$ is real-valued — such a function always exists, and it is defined up to a set of zero measure with respect to the distribution of $Y$.)

Comment: Are you saying that the value $y \in \mathbb{R}$ is irrelevant?

Comment: What I want to say is that $E[X|Y=y]$ defines a function of $y$ (or, more precisely, it is an expression that defines a function of the free variable $y$, up to equality almost everywhere with respect to the distribution of $Y$). For a fixed $y$, this is typically not well-defined. Note that in a similar way, one commonly writes e.g. $\sin x$ for a *function* of $x$ rather than the value for a particular $x$. Just a useful short-hand notation.

Comment: Oh that helps a lot; one question though: why would one not write $E[X | Y](y)$ just like we write $\sin(x)$?

Comment: Also, could you point me to a proof about the existence of such a function if $Y$ is real-valued?

Comment: The symbol $E[X|Y]$ has a well-established different meaning: it is a random variable. Existence of the function $f$ is a consequence of the Doob–Dynkin lemma. It has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma) with some references, see also [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/263863/108637) for further discussion. (Apparently this is a [homework problem at Cornell](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~web6710/Math%206710%20HW2.pdf).)